# How to change ProductCode using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, setup-deployment

In a deployment scenario we had the idea to allow an administrator to change properties in a installer and the ProductCode. The administrator should then push out the newer msi using a GPO policy. Since this now would be a MajorUpgrade the old version, with the old properties, should be uninstalled and the new one, with the new properties, should be installed.
However updating the ProductCode doesn't work.

When executing
`db.Execute("UPDATE Property SET Value = '{30571D61-8994-449B-9725-90760DFE0467}' WHERE Property = 'ProductCode'")`
an exception is thrown.
`[Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.InstallerException] = {"Function failed during execution. Database: C:\..\MyInstaller.msi Table(s) Update failed."}`

What should I do to upgrade the ProductCode?
(Is it even possible?)

**Edit:**
If the table is opened as ReadOnly, it will show error.
Which was the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDK documentation states that ExecuteScalar can only be used for a SELECT statement that returns a single result.  Instead you should use the Execute method.

```
using (Database database = new Database(@"C:\MSM\ISWIX.MSI", DatabaseOpenMode.Direct))
{
    database.Execute("UPDATE Property SET Value = '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}' WHERE Property = 'ProductCode'");
}
```

Also realize this cannot be done as a custom action during the installation as ProductCode is immutable.   Typically in a MajorUpgrade scenario you assign a new ProductCode at build/compile time.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I am actually using Execute.
I found the error. My wrapper-class had an inverted if, so I opened readonly when I wanted to modify.